# Storing Green Onions?

Tags: food-safety, storage-method

What is the proper method to store green onions? Additionally, how long can it be stored in the chill chest?

Comment: Whatever you do, don't forget to toss the roots in a container or jar with fresh water -- they'll grow back 1-2 times, depending on how vigilant you are with keeping the water clean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to chop them up, and preserve them in an acidic solution that you allow to ferment a little.  Then, just keep it in the fridge as long as you like.  Additionally, the onions will become tastier, easier to digest and will have an improved nutritional profile.

The acidic solution can be any mixture of water with salt, sugar, vinegar, spices, whey, yogurt, wine, beer, lemon juice, etc...The options are endless.  This is called your brine and people have been using this method of preservation for millions of years.

As far as storing fresh onions, your best bet is to keep them in the refrigerator's crisper drawer which helps keep vegetables fresher longer.

Answer (score 4):

I wash them and take off the outer skin part and cut off the roots, of course. I chop them into half inch pieces. Put them in a tupperware with a paper towel underneath.  Put the lid on and put them in the fridge. Keep it loose, don't stuff them in there.  I sprinkle them on everything I eat.  Change your paper towel if it gets moist.

Comment: You can plant green onions all year, from seed.  Just find a spot and plant the seeds. They winter over and if you plant them at different times you will have green onions all year long. Any pot will do also, put a dozen in with your geraniums or other pots.

Answer (score 1):

I wrap them in some paper towel, and then put them back in the bag I bought them in. Then, put them in the crisper drawer. Most herbs tend to last longer for me like that.

Comment: agreed ... I can get a week out of leafy herbs this way, and even longer out of hertier herbs such as green onions.

Answer (score 1):

Lately I have been putting them in a glass with an inch or so of water in it, loosely covering them with a plastic bag, and putting them upright on a shelf in my fridge. I've found that they can easily stay fresh this way for a week or two provided I change the water sometimes (or add more when necessary) and occasionally shake out any condensation that may accumulate on the bag.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried dehydration method of preserving herbs?

Green onions don't lose their flavour and colour if dried properly, and they last for long time if stored properly in airtight container.

Try drying them even if you don't own a dehydrator it is simple. Just chop them up in cubes, put some baking paper on a tray, spread the chopped pieces on the paper and let them in an oven with its fan turned on. Or simply leave the tray in cool corner of your kitchen.